# What is the simple form of this complex sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence

I am little bit confused of making this complex sentence into simple sentence. The sentence is:

> As I was ill, I could not attend the class.

However, I made three types of simple sentence of this but don't know which is more precise and correct. The three simple sentences are given below:

> 1. Being ill, I could not attend the class.
> 2. I could not attend the class being ill.
> 3. I could not attend the class for being ill.

Are they all correct? Are they have the same meaning? If not please then please clarify.

Comment: What do you believe a simple sentence to be? Here's a hint: the first rephrased sentence is no different than the original in terms of what you're after.

Comment: None of them are simple sentences. You have two clauses, so any way you arrange them, as long as they're both in the same sentence, it's not simple. There is usually not a "simple form" of a complex or compound sentence; if there were, we'd never need anything else.

Comment: Is this an exercise for a class?  A desire to write more like Hemingway?  I don't know if this would help, but maybe *I could not attend class due to illness* or *I was out sick yesterday* -- I just don't know what the parameters of this exercise are.

Comment: Verbs function as heads of clauses, i.e. a verb indicates the presence of a clause. Two verbs indicate two clauses, three verbs indicate three clauses, and so on. There's no way round this.

Comment: I was out sick?

Comment: The original sentence (A) and the first rephrased sentence (B) are different in that A contains two clauses each with a subject and a finite verb and B only one of each. Traditionally, in English classes in school, A would be called a complex sentence and B would be called simple. See for example Warriner's _Middle School Handbook_: _A clause is a group of words that contains a verb and its subject_  (p9). And _A simple sentence has one independent clause and no subordinate clauses_. (p33)

Comment: Don't you think you'd get more useful help somewhere like SE English Language Learning?

Answer (score -1):

As the comments already have stated, having two clauses in on sentence can be very hard to come up with a simple sentence solution. With this in mind, I am thinking that by simple sentence, you meant a sentence that is easier to understand or is easier to construct. Going with this assumption, here are some sentences I could come up with, that seem simpler to me than the original one: 
"Hence I was ill, I could not attend class." or "I was ill, therefore I couldn't attend class." Since "hence" and "therefore" are conjunctions, they help in forming a sentence from otherwise two different sentences.